# The Borel sigma algebra on a set $X$ is always a boolean algebra? (With union, intersection and set complementation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, logic, category-theory

I am studying Topos quantum theory. I was reading that the spectral algebra of a bounded operator is isomorphic as Boolean algebra, to Borel sigma algebra of its spectrum.

Comment: Of course. Every $\sigma$-algebra has closure under complements and finite intersections, which already gives a Boolean algebra structure.